# IIS Impersonation calling powershell thread?

Tags: powershell, iis

I am newly learning IIS, and I am trying to use IIS to host an app to impersonate an Administrative user, then execute powershell command as Admin to add users to local groups.

Within in ASP.NET code, I am running the following:

```
private string RunScript()
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            PowerShell psExec = PowerShell.Create();
            psExec.AddCommand(SCRIPT_LOCATION);
            psExec.AddParameter("username",Username.Text);
            psExec.AddParameter("computer", Computer.Text);
            psExec.AddParameter("group", Group.Text);

            Collection<PSObject> results;

            stringBuilder.AppendLine(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);

            results = psExec.Invoke();
            //errors = psExec.Streams.Error.ReadAll();
            foreach (PSObject result in results)
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(result.ToString());
            }
            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
```

In my web.config, I have the following added:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="True" userName="<My admin user name>" password="<My admin password>"/>
```

So my GetCurrent().Name seems to return that I am at least running the application as my admin username. But when calling my powershell script:

```
Write-Output whoami
```

Returns that I am **NT Authority\System**.

In my IIS:
**Application pool Identity** is **"LocalSystem"**
**Authentication** setting has **ASP.NET Impersonation** (where admin user is set as **Specific user**) is enabled.
**Windows Authentication** is enabled.

So when I try to add the user to group, I get "Access is denied". Just as a sanity check, I have confirmed that if I run the powershell script separately as Admin, the add works fine.

I am sure it's something basic I am missing, but if anyone would please provide any advice or guidance, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `<identity>` should not be used. Change the application pool identity to an admin.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So I have tried removing <identity> from web.config and set the application pool identity as admin. Now when the powershell script runs I receive NullReferenceException. Which seems strange to me, when I run the script by itself with same parameters, it completes without issues. Why does this exception occur then script is ran from IIS? Also, I noticed the script actually worked, the user was added. But I am directed to "Server Error in '/' Application" page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the `psExec.Invoke()` method creates a thread called “Pipeline Execution Thread” and the command/script is executed in this new thread. By default the impersonation token does not flow across threads, so “Pipeline Execution Thread” doesn’t get the impersonation token of the calling thread.

You can configure ASP.Net to flow the impersonation token to newly created threads by using “alwaysFlowImpersonationPolicy” and “legacyImpersonationPolicy” configuration elements in asp.config file like this:

```
            <runtime>

                         <legacyImpersonationPolicy enabled=”false”/>

                         <alwaysFlowImpersonationPolicy enabled=”true”/>

           </runtime>
```

More details about how to set it, you could refer to below article:
https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/setting-an-aspnet-config-file-per-application-pool

Comment: Thank you for the answer! So I have tried to update the aspnet.config file like you have suggested then restarted from IIS. The article stated to recycle the applicaiton pool, so I did that as well. Unfortunately I am still seeing the same issue. Would there be a step to make sure my application pool is picking up the aspnet.config file properly?

Comment: Could you please tell me which knid of asp.net version you have used now?

Comment: According to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4, the version is 4.8.03761. There were aspnet.config file in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 and ...\v4.0.30319 but I did try editing both config files as well.